# Numpy use an array to slice the indices of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

**Context:** I have a 2D array `A` that I would like to modify at specific indices, given by the arrays `a1` and `a2`. I could use a `for loop` but I want to optimize this problem.

**Problem:** The way I modify my array needs to use `a2` as a slice: `A[a1, a2:] = 1000`. But I can't manage to get past `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. How could I do that value replacement of `A` faster than with loops ?

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize array
A = np.zeros((10,10),int)

    
# Create two arrays of indices
a1 = np.array([1,5,6], dtype = int)
a2 = np.array([4,6,2], dtype = int)

# As a for loop
for i in range(a1.shape[0]):
    A[a1[i], a2[i]:] = 10

# What I tried (doesn't work)
A[a1, a2:]

A
Out[452]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Since the rows and columns are being indexed over different arrays, I don't think you can avoid looping: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60279765/7776212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example, tweaked for easier display:

```
In [450]: A = np.zeros((10,10),int)
     ...: # Create two arrays of indices
     ...: a1 = np.array([1,5,6], dtype = int)
     ...: a2 = np.array([4,6,2], dtype = int)
     ...: 

In [451]: for i in range(a1.shape[0]):
     ...:     A[a1[i], a2[i]:] = 10
     ...: 

In [452]: A
Out[452]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Ranges can be converted to advanced indexing arrays.  In this case:

```
In [453]: idx2=np.arange(10)>=a2[:,None]
In [454]: idx2
Out[454]: 
array([[False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True]])
```

And we can find the '10s' in `A` with:

```
In [455]: A[a1][idx2]
Out[455]: 
array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
       10])
```

This approach is inspired by various posts about padding lists of various lengths.

But we can't use that to set values in `A`.  I'll have to do some more experimenting to get that to work.

### edit

Define another index that covers all rows:

```
In [459]: a3 = np.zeros(10,int)+10; a3[a1]=a2    
In [460]: a3
Out[460]: array([10,  4, 10, 10, 10,  6,  2, 10, 10, 10])
```

Then make the mask:

```
In [461]: idx2=np.arange(10)>=a3[:,None]
In [462]: idx2
Out[462]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False]])
```

Test the fetch:

```
In [463]: A[idx2]
Out[463]: 
array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
       10])
```

and the set:

```
In [464]: A[idx2]=20

In [465]: A
Out[465]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20],
       [ 0,  0, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Should I wait for you to modify your code or should I accept it as an answer and close the topic ? 
I wasn't expecting my question to actually touch something non-trivial !